# How can I control timer555 source voltage with another timer555 frequency?

Tags: 555

How can I control timer555 source voltage with another timer555 oscillator ? I want to make a oscillator and control it`s source voltage with another timer555 saw wave oscillator. I did a 758Khz timer555 oscillator and I connected another timer555 saw wave oscillator to voltage source transistor. But It can change another timer555 voltage source only 0.8 volt.  I need 3 volt voltage source changing. For example timer555 voltage source 12 volt 11.50 volt 10.50 volt 9 volt voltage change I need. How I can solve this timer555 problem ? This is my multisim circuit. Problem is this. It only changing source voltage 0.8 volt. But I need 3 volt voltage changing.

[image]

*Figure 1*

---

okay I changed two transistor and I put only p channel one transistor. Can it work with this circuit ?   It has 6 volt and 12 volt changing voltage.

[image]

*Figure 2*

---

[image]

*Figure 3*

okay I want to do this. I did it with easy way fucntion generator in multisim. Voltage is 6 volt 7 volt 8 volt 9 volt 10 volt 11 volt 12 volt after 11 volt 10 volt 9 volt 8 volt 7 volt 6 volt. I want to change voltage source slowly with another timer 555 trapezoid wave with connected to it a P channel transistor. Are you sure about mosfet use ? Multisim is giving error all of mosfets to me. Square wave can not do this because when it has 0 volt signal source , other timer 555 is stopping.

[image: Wanted result]

[image: studying result]

Okay I added my wanted result and studing result. I want to build a control oscillator that controls the amount of voltage of a 750Khz timer 555 frontier, and then gets up and down slowly. As in the figure, the voltage will slowly decrease to 12 volts 11 volts 10 volts 9 volts 8 volts 7 volts 6 volts. Then increase the voltage slowly. Example 6 volts 7 volts 8 volts 9 volts 10 volts 11 volts 12 volts. But the timer 555 control oscillator in my work does not provide this. I want the other oscillator to check its voltage but it just distorts its signal. It is disrupting the signal when the voltage source should be slowly up and down. I'm searching its fault reason.

Comment: Explain what you're trying to achieve, what kind of waveform do you want? What is "source voltage", perhaps you mean "supply voltage". Why would you want to control the supply voltage? Changing the supply voltage of an IC is generally not a good idea and can lead to unexpected results. If you just want to switch on/off the 2nd 555 circuit then use the RESET input for that.

Comment: It's an NE555, LM555, or any number of other clones of the original NE555, but definitely not "timer555".

Comment: Hidden in the comments to an answer below you have revealed that you're trying to make a trapezoidal signal generator. This information should be in your question. Why are you using a 555 for this? Look for op-amp triangle generator instead.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what the finished result you require is rather than how you think it should be done. Write a specification like, "**I would like to generate a 750 kHz squarewave whose amplitude is modulated by a triangle wave at 1.2 kHz so that the squarewave varies from 6 V peak to 12 V peak. The load will be a resistance of 10 kΩ. Supply voltage is 12 V DC.**" (That is my best understanding of your question.)

Comment: Okay I added my wanted and studing results . I want to make a voltage control oscillator to control another oscillator voltage. For example It is changing voltage source 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 volt and change again 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 . I want to obtain this. But timer 555 is persistently disturbing other timer 55 oscillator signal in multisim circuit

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use Q2 and Q1 transistors? Use just Q1 transistor, and I think the 1KOhm resistor is not needed.

Also I think your Q1 is Upside down, NPN transistor the current flows to the direction of the arrow (From Emitter to collector)

[image]

EDIT:

Referring to the figure 2 of your new circuit:

Q1 will turn fully on when the Base voltage of Q1 is 0. If your C2 is low enough to let the Vbase of Q1 to be 0, the transistor will turn fully on, and I guess it will work then. I would recommend lowering the C2 to 10nF, or even 1nF.

Comment: But I need a trapezoid wave. it means. The voltage should work like this. 6 volts 6.30 volts 7.30 volts 8.80 volts 9 volts 10 volts 11 volts 12 volts. Then 12 volts 11 volts 10 volts 9 volts 8 volts 7 volts 6 volts. I'm trying to do this. That's why I'm trying to get a trapezoid wave. I have added a 20nf capacitor. The wave bent a little more. Could high capacitor value cause problems?

Comment: If you want trapezoidal waveforms (triangle) then you need to charge/discharge via constant current.

Comment: @MuratÖzen Edit your question as transistor says to include the rest of the relevant information.  Draw a graph and add it to your question to describe the waveform you want.

Comment: @MuratÖzen If you need a trapezoid wave you will need a mosfet. Transistors control current, so your voltage might not be in trapezoid shape/waveform

Comment: Okay I did it with function generator and share picture. I updated my question .